# Count SQL column names starting with a word

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a SQL Server table that has columns `Blocks 1`, `Blocks 2` and `Blocks 3`.

If all of these columns have data in them already my program will create another column in my table programmatically with the next blocks number. In this case, the next heading that will be created will be `Blocks 4`.

This already works with a hack (shown below in code) that will not work when I have another column that fluctuates in the number of columns in my table.

```
con.Open()           
Cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * From [Official] WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(50), ID) ='" + Session("ID") + "'", con)
dr1 = Cmd.ExecuteReader
dr1.Read()

'If I add or removed columns in official table I need to add or subtract to number below!!!

Dim NumberOfBlocks As Integer = dr1.VisibleFieldCount - 15 'minus 15 because that is the number of items other than blocks within officials table
```

So here is my question so I don't have to do the unreliable hack above:

How do I count how many times my table has a column name that starts with the word "Blocks"?

I would like to be able to do this in Visual Basic using SQL syntax or in SQL only.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Microsoft SQL is what I am using

Comment: Then you need to edit your question and add the tag `sql-server`

Comment: `column names of "Blocks 1", "Blocks 2", and "Blocks 3"` Sounds like your DB is missing a 1:m (or perhaps m:m) relationship.  Make it so that table can have many Blocks associated with it and you wont have to count columns

Comment: Your schema sounds like it's not great so you are going to run into issues like this over and over again. Just the same, I believe you want to get `dr1.GetSchemaTable()` [infohere](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx). That returns a `datatable` type object that you can hit up for column names of the `SqlDataReader` object `dr1` in your code. I would write this up as an answer but I haven't written vb.net in like 8 years so I would surely botch the actual implementation of the code.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you could use the following

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'llf_promotion' and column_name like '%block%'
```

I my example I am searching the table **llf_promotion** to get a list of columns that contain the word **block** using the sql server wildcard %.  If I wanted instead to find any column that started with block I would use "column_name like 'block%'" where I only have the wildcard character at the end.

With the following you can get just the count instead of the list of columns as shown above.

```
select count(*) 
    from information_schema.columns 
    where table_name = 'llf_promotion' and column_name like '%block%'
```

Comment: How would I then use this count in my next select statemen? For instance If I had 3 columns starting with blocks my select statement later would only select Blocks 1, Blocks 2, and Blocks 3

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do but it seems to me that you might be better off housing the block data in a separate table as opposed to adding new columns each time.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I count how many times my table has a column name that starts with the word "Blocks"?

The SQL syntax you would want to use for a simple count would look something like this:

```
select count(*) from tablename foo where foo.columnname = 'Blocks'
```

Or for a wild card like this:

```
select count(*) from tablename foo where foo.columnname like 'Blocks%'
```

You could store the output value as a variable and use it in the rest of your program.

> The field name/column name is what OP is after. Not a field named "ColumnName"

In that case, you would want to do this:

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'foo' and column_name = 'Blocks'
```

Same thing applies using the wildcard.

Comment: The field name/column name is what OP is after. Not a field named "ColumnName"

Answer (score -1):

With the help from some of the posts, I was able to search for an answer better and have the following solution.

This is an example of how you can accomplish this within visual basic after a select command and data reader has been used.

The code below is getting the column name from each column and checking to see if it starts with the word "Blocks" and then counts them for use later in my program. Thanks for your help.

```
Dim CountBlocks As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To dr1.VisibleFieldCount - 1
    If dr1.GetName(i).StartsWith("Blocks") Then
    CountBlocks = CountBlocks + 1
    Else
    'Dont count
    End If
Next
```